# CSS 3Dtransform z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a book in web, when I turn the page on my book, it goes under the cover, but I need it to be on top. I'll just give you the demo:

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vill3/5tpekxwu/1/

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
z-index: -100;
```

(or any negative z-index) to `.open` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

To the cover.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But that solution hides the cover completely. I need it to be shown atleast as long the first page is open